# ¿Cómo acceder a los elementos de un $array[] en php?

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$sql = "CALL bd.spPrueba()";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

    while ($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $json = json_encode($row);

    }

} else {

    echo "0 results";

}

echo $json;

$conn->close();
```

Y me da el siguiente resultado:

```
[{"Clave":"79","Tiempo":"02:23:43","Estatus":"Si","FechaInicio":"2017-03-06 13:02:41"}]
```

Pero si yo deseo obtener cada resultado para guardarlo en una variable, es decir esto:

```
 $sql = "CALL bd.spPrueba()";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

         while ($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

             $Clave = $row["Clave"];
             $Tiempo = $row["Tiempo"];

             echo "<br>";
             echo "Clave = ".$Clave;
             echo "<br>";
             echo "Tiempo = ".$Tiempo;

             $json = json_encode($row);

         }

     } else {

         echo "0 results";

     }

     echo $json;
     $conn->close();
```

Simplemente no funciona y no me guarda nada, solo me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Clave = 
Tiempo = 
[{"Clave":"79","Tiempo":"02:23:43","Estatus":"Si","FechaInicio":"2017-03-06 13:02:41"}]
```

A menos que le quite los corchetes a la variable `$row` en el `while` es decir así:

```
$sql = "CALL bd.spPrueba()";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $Clave = $row["Clave"];
        $Tiempo = $row["Tiempo"];

        echo "<br>";
        echo "Clave = ".$Clave;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Tiempo = ".$Tiempo;

        $json = json_encode($row);

    }

} else {

    echo "0 results";

}

echo $json;
$conn->close();
```

Y me daría el siguiente resultado:

```
Clave = 79
Tiempo = 02:23:43
{"Clave":"79","Tiempo":"02:23:43","Estatus":"Si","FechaInicio":"2017-03-06 13:02:41"}
```

Si le hago un `var_dump();`

En `$row[]` puedo ver lo siguiente:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["Clave"]=> string(2) "79" ["Tiempo"]=> string(8) "02:50:30" ["Estatus"]=> string(5) "Si" ["FechaInicio"]=> string(19) "2017-03-06 13:29:27" } }
```

En `row` puedo ver lo siguiente:

```
array(8) { ["Clave"]=> string(2) "79" ["Tiempo"]=> string(8) "02:51:04" ["Estatus"]=> string(5) "Si" ["FechaInicio"]=> string(19) "2017-03-06 13:30:01" }
```

A mi me gustaría dejar los corchetes pero que me guarde los campos en variables de `php` porque si le quito los corchetes el `arrayJson` que tengo en Android truena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que está pasando es que estás guardando un objeto de `row` en cada posición del `array` `row[]`, entonces deberías de poder entrar con el índice y el nombre del campo, cuando imprimes prueba con esto.

```
$Clave = $row[0]["Clave"];
$Tiempo = $row[0]["Tiempo"];
echo "<br>";
echo "Clave = ".$Clave;
echo "<br>";
echo "Tiempo = ".$Tiempo;
```

Si imprimes algo con eso entonces lleva un iterador para que puedas ir guardando los valores.

Comment: Si imprime el 1er valor, a que te refieres con un iterador?

Comment: una variable que te vaya llevfando la cuenta de en que posición estas, declarala fuera del while e inicializala en 0 , despues ve actualizandola de 1 en 1 y asi vas a ir iterando en los diferentes elementos que tiene tu arreglo row

Comment: Lo hice con un foreach y ya obtengo el resultado que quiero, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
     $Clave = $row["Clave"];
     $Tiempo = $row["Tiempo"];
     ....
}
```

No debería darte problema después.

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo resultado

Comment: @ElCóndor, vuelve a probar este código, debe darte el resultado que estás buscando.

Comment: Si el detalle esta que yo ocupo guardar el array en `$row[]` y en el ejemplo funciona perfecto pero solo para `$row`